# Incrementally comparing multiple value sets or lists between two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to compare two sets of values between 2 Oracle tables as below. I am trying to look for and match groups of data in table B with those in table A. The group number is common between tables

Its considered a match only if all groups and values under an id in Table A are equal the group and value pair in Table B. I have highlighted the 'matches' in green. Table A could have variable number of group/value pairs under ida value. There could be ids that have only one group/value pair and there could be some that have 3 group/value pairs

### Comparison Example

```
  Ida GroupA Vala|GroupB Valb| Match?
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  50    1     4  |  1     1  | No - Value doesn't match
  56    1     5  |  1     1  | No - Value doesn't match
  57    1     1  |  1     1  | Yes - Both Groups (1&2) and Values match
  57    2    101 |  2    101 | Yes - Both Group (1&2)and Values match
  94    1     1  |  1     1  | Yes - Group and Value match
  96    1     1  |  1     1  | No - Only group 1 matches
  96    2    102 |  2    101 | No - Only group 1 matches. Group 2 doesn't
```

### Trial (and Error!)

I figured I would have to use some sort of count and tried using a partition by to count the groups in Table A. But, I am not sure how to use this in a query to do a sequential/multi value comparison. I looked up hierarchical functions but realized they may not fit here.. What would be the best approach to deal with such data comparison? Thanks for your help..

Happy Halloween! :)

```
select a.*,MAX(a.groupa) OVER (PARTITION BY a.ida ORDER BY a.groupa desc) 
occurs 
from tab_a a, tab_b b
where a.groupa=b.groupb and a.vala=b.valb
and a.groupa<=3
```

### Tables

[Tables A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLcwU.png)

```
create table tab_a   
(                    
ida number,         
groupa number, 
vala number
)

create table tab_b
(   
idb number, 
groupb number, 
valb number
)
```

### Data

```
insert into tab_a values (50,1,4);
insert into tab_a values (56,1,5);
insert into tab_a values (57,1,1);
insert into tab_a values (57,2,101);
insert into tab_a values (58,1,1);
insert into tab_a values (58,2,104);
insert into tab_a values (60,2,102);
insert into tab_a values (94,1,1);
insert into tab_a values (95,1,1);
insert into tab_a values (95,2,101);
insert into tab_a values (96,1,1);
insert into tab_a values (96,2,102);
insert into tab_a values (97,1,1);
insert into tab_a values (97,2,101);
insert into tab_a values (97,3,201);

insert into tab_b values (752,1,1);
insert into tab_b values (752,2,101);
insert into tab_b values (752,3,201);
```

Comment: Mind blown.  Love the question.   The only logical issue I see is can you guarantee that each group and value combination is unique?  I see having to use a CTE to do this to first identify matching data, and then select off the cte or subquery to ensure all records for a group match; and if not identify the ones that did vs didn't using listagg or something.  Defiantly a question I'll be thinking about.

Comment: Why are only some IDs listed at all; why aren't there any rows for 58 for instance?

Comment: maybe this is a simple A left join B on A.GroupA = B.GroupB and A.ValA = B.valA and then a count of the non null B values vs non-null A values. matching counts = all reocrds match non-matching non null counts mean some matched and we could use listagg or wm_concat to identify them.   whereas NULL values mean didn't match at all.  still pondering...

Comment: Is your goal to output a result set like your comparison?  If so, is `groupb` unique in `tab_b`?  If not, how do you know which non-matching row from `b` to display in the comparison for a particular row in `a`?  Or is your goal to output just those rows where there is a match (which is a bit easier)?

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. @xQbert - No, the values across groups aren't unique. Using the same example above, two groups can have the same values, group 2 can have the value 1 as well

Comment: @AlexPoole - I had just used some examples in my text for easy understanding. The attached image has all the matches/non-matches highlighted. Specifically, id 58 is not a match as the group 2 value (104) doesn't match the value 101, only the group 1 value matches..

Comment: @JustinCave - My goal is to just find out the matches in Table B. I had used the example report just for illustration purposes for easy understanding..

Comment: So - let's see if I understand the question. There may be a solution with no joins. Table A has several `ida` values, and for each such value, there are one or more pairs (`grp, val`). Table B has several pairs (`grp, val`). You want to find all the `ida` from table A where all its pairs can be found in table B. Is that the problem, or do you also need the Match table, with a full explanation of what matches and what doesn't? And - can there be duplicate pairs for an `ida` in table A, and/or duplicate pairs (same `grp` and `val` at the same time) in table B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is all the way there but might get you started. You can do:

```
select a.*, b.*,
  count(case when a.groupa = b.groupb and a.vala = b.valb then a.ida end)
    over (partition by a.ida) match_count,
  count(distinct a.groupa||':'||a.vala)
    over (partition by a.ida) val_count
from tab_a a
full outer join tab_b b on b.groupb = a.groupa and b.valb = a.vala
where a.groupa <= 3;
```

The `distinct` may not be needed, and the concatenation with the colon needs to use a characters that isn't in any real value, I suppose, to avoid potential for false matched.

That gets:

```
IDA GROUPA VALA  IDB GROUPB VALB MATCH_COUNT  VAL_COUNT
--- ------ ---- ---- ------ ---- ----------- ----------
 50      1    4                            0          1
 56      1    5                            0          1
 57      1    1  752      1    1           2          2
 57      2  101  752      2  101           2          2
 58      1    1  752      1    1           1          2
 58      2  104                            1          2
 60      2  102                            0          1
 94      1    1  752      1    1           1          1
 95      1    1  752      1    1           2          2
 95      2  101  752      2  101           2          2
 96      1    1  752      1    1           1          2
 96      2  102                            1          2
 97      1    1  752      1    1           3          3
 97      2  101  752      2  101           3          3
 97      3  201  752      3  201           3          3
```

And then use that as a CTE or inline view and decode the results:

```
with t as (
  select a.ida, a.groupa, a.vala, b.groupb, b.valb,
    count(case when a.groupa = b.groupb and a.vala = b.valb then a.ida end)
      over (partition by a.ida) match_count,
    count(distinct a.groupa||':'||a.vala)
      over (partition by a.ida) val_count
  from tab_a a
  full outer join tab_b b on b.groupb = a.groupa and b.valb = a.vala
  where a.groupa <= 3
)
select ida, groupa, vala, groupb, valb,
  case
    when match_count = 0 then 'No - Value doesn''t match'
    when match_count = val_count and val_count = 1
      then 'Yes - Group and Value match'
    when match_count = val_count and val_count = 2
      then 'Yes - Both Group (1&2) and Values match'
    when match_count < val_count and val_count = 2 and valb is not null
      then 'No - Only group 1 matches'
    when match_count < val_count and val_count = 2 and valb is null
      then 'No - Only group 1 matches. Group 2 doesn''t'
    else 'Unknown scenario?'
  end as "Match?"
from t;
```

Which gets:

```
IDA GROUPA VALA GROUPB VALB Match?                                    
--- ------ ---- ------ ---- ------------------------------------------
 50      1    4             No - Value doesn't match                  
 56      1    5             No - Value doesn't match                  
 57      1    1      1    1 Yes - Both Group (1&2) and Values match   
 57      2  101      2  101 Yes - Both Group (1&2) and Values match   
 58      1    1      1    1 No - Only group 1 matches                 
 58      2  104             No - Only group 1 matches. Group 2 doesn't
 60      2  102             No - Value doesn't match                  
 94      1    1      1    1 Yes - Group and Value match               
 95      1    1      1    1 Yes - Both Group (1&2) and Values match   
 95      2  101      2  101 Yes - Both Group (1&2) and Values match   
 96      1    1      1    1 No - Only group 1 matches                 
 96      2  102             No - Only group 1 matches. Group 2 doesn't
 97      1    1      1    1 Yes - All Group (1&2&3) and Values match  
 97      2  101      2  101 Yes - All Group (1&2&3) and Values match  
 97      3  201      3  201 Yes - All Group (1&2&3) and Values match
```

I think that gets the match result you showed in your examples; not sure if the others you didn't show are what you want... ID 97 matches on three groups/values, and it's easy enough to do:

```
    when match_count = val_count and val_count = 3
      then 'Yes - All Group (1&2&3) and Values match'
```

for that exact match, but figuring out what to show if one or two of those three match is trickier. You could also capture the min and max B values that do match and work out from those which one(s) are missing; but then you might add a fourth group, and it doesn't scale.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I found Alex's approach most intuitive so far to help solve this problem. @Alex - The report with the text was just for illustration purposes, the expected output was just the matches from Table B

Comment: @Kacper - Thanks for sharing the approach. I replaced the OR in the first CASE with AND statement, the result seems to flag some non-matches as matches

Comment: @Sofia - your second comment is on the wrong answer *8-) Not quite sure what the first ones means. If you want to display values for the non-matches in B you can use `coalesce(groupb, groupa)` or just repeat `groupa` - but either way is there any point showing the values twice?

Answer (score 2):

This query should work:

```
select a.ida
from tab_a a
where a.groupa||a.vala in 
  (select b.groupb|| b.valb from tab_b b where b.groupb = a.groupa )
group by a.ida
having count(distinct a.groupa||a.vala) = 
  (select count(distinct a1.groupa||a1.vala) 
    from tab_a a1 
    where a1.ida = a.ida)
```

Bit of explanation:

> ```
> 1. where clause gets all the rows from tab_a 
>      that exist in tab_b for a group+val combo. 
>      - So let's say there are 2 (out of 2) rows in tab_a 
>        that match with 2(out of 3) rows in tab_b.
>
> 2. left hand side of the having clause adds 
>       a condition to the found rows such that 
>       total number of rows of distinct group+val must equal to
>       - So here we start comparing that count 2
>
> 3. right hand side of the having clause 
>       that provides the total number of 
>       distinct group+val (regardless of any match with tab_b).
>       - here we enforce that left hand side must be equal
>         to the total number of rows found. So if in #2 above, 
>         only 1 row of table_a matched (out of its 2 rows), 
>         then #3 will exclude that set.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the perfect one but match_strength 2 means that both are matched and match_strength 1 means you match only one column.

```
select * from (
select a.*, b.*, case when (a.vala = b.valb and a.groupa = b.groupb) then 2 
                      when (a.vala = b.valb or a.groupa = b.groupb) then 1 
                      else 0 end as match_strength,
                  row_number() over (partition by a.rowid order by 
                  case when (a.vala = b.valb and a.groupa = b.groupb) then 2 
                      when (a.vala = b.valb or a.groupa = b.groupb) then 1 
                      else 0 end desc) r
from tab_a a, tab_b b)
where r = 1;
```

If you want to know exactly which column matches you can play with order by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the requirement is to find all the `ida` for which all the pairs `groupa, vala` can be found in `table_b` (with no further information on why the ones that failed, failed) you could use the query below. The inner query actually shows why the ones that failed, failed (if you select `*` instead of just the `ida`). There is only one unusual thing in this solution - I have heard of the use of IN condition (and similar) for pairs, or tuples in general, instead of scalar values, but I hadn't used it till today. I just tested on your data and it works perfectly fine.

This works in the following general sense: it is not necessary to assume that `groupa` is unique for each `ida`, or the same for `table_b`; that is, `(ida, groupa)` does not have to be unique in the first table, nor does `(idb, groupb)` in the second table.

```
select distinct ida from tab_a where ida not in
      (select ida from tab_a where (groupa, vala) not in (select groupb, valb from tab_b));

   IDA
------
    57
    95
    94
    97
```